# WinError 10061 and WinError 10022 in socket programming only on Windows

Tags: python, linux, sockets, window, try-except

I have a very simple Python code for `bind` or `connect` to a port. it works without any error on `Ubuntu` and `CentOs` but I have an error on `Windows 10`. I turned off the firewall and antivirus but it didn't help.

my code:

```
import socket

port = 9999

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = socket.gethostname()


try:
    s.connect((host,port))
except:
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(1)
    print("I'm a server")
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
else:
    print("I'm a client")
```

error on windows 10:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "win.py", line 11, in <module>
    s.connect((host,port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During the handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "win.py", line 13, in <module>
    s.bind((host, port))
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

Edit:

I found my problem is in `Try... Except` part, if I put this code in two files my problem will solve. But Why? `try except` don't work correctly in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

The `connect()` fails because there is no server socket listening at `(host,port)`.

The `bind()` fails because you can't bind to a hostname, only to an IP address.  Unless you want to listen on just a specific network interface, you should bind to `0.0.0.0` to listen on all interfaces.

Comment: this file must run two times, first, as you said, there is no server socket and an exception will occur and `s.bind((host, port))` will execute to establish a server. and when this file runs for the second time it can connect to the socket and be a client.

Comment: @Ehsan Simply change `s.bind((host, port))` to `s.bind(("0.0.0.0", port))` or `s.bind(("", port))`, and then it should work.  Alternatively, change `host = socket.gethostname()` to `host = "127.0.0.1"` instead, and then it should also work.